# I don't have a param key in my Rails Application. How do I either work around it or set one up so I can save the value to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, parameter-passing

I don't have a key for my params so when it asks for a key in params.require(), I am not sure what to put. Can someone tell me either how to get around it or set one up?

Here is new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @postings1314 do |r| %>
  <div>
    <%=r.label :firstName%>
    <%=r.text_field :firstName%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=r.label :lastName%>
    <%=r.text_field :lastName%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=r.label :age%>
    <%=r.text_field :age%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=r.label :bio%>
    <%=r.text_field :bio%>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%=r.submit%>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Here is my grouponepostings_controller.rb:

```
class GrouponepostingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @postings1314 = Grouponepage.all
  end
  def show
    @posting1314singular = Grouponepage.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @postings1314 = Grouponepage.new
  end
  def create
    page_params = params.require().permit(:firstName, :lastName, :age, :bio)
    @posting1314 = Grouponepage.new(page_params)
    @posting1314.save
    redirect_to '/grouponepostings'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add your actual params to your question (by using the edit button below the tags)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "require()" method is not required, what you really need are the permitted parameters. You can do params.permit(:firstName, :lastName, :age, :bio) and it should work as long as your params object actually have those keys at the root of the object...

...which is weird since rails adds a grapper key by default for all the fields when using the form helpers and an object, you should have a key :groupenpage to use inside the required() call.